# Windows thread scheduler is unfair?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, cpu, scheduler

Sometimes, when I run this simple program

```
#include <Windows.h>

DWORD WINAPI ThreadStart(LPVOID)
{
    for (;;) { }
    return 0;
}

int _tmain()
{
    SetPriorityClass(GetCurrentProcess(), BELOW_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS);

    SYSTEM_INFO si;
    GetSystemInfo(&si);
    for (DWORD i = si.dwNumberOfProcessors * 2; i > 0; i--)
    { CloseHandle(CreateThread(NULL, 0, &ThreadStart, NULL, 0, NULL)); }

    Sleep(INFINITE);
}
```

I observe constantly unfair thread scheduling, such as:

[image: Screenshot]

It's not unfair on every run, but when it *is*, it stays unfair throughout the lifetime of the application.

Why does this happen, and what is the proper way to avoid it?

Comment: What mode of CPU do you have?  Is it actually a quad-core, or is it dual-core with hyperthreading?

Comment: Also, what version of Windows.  That is also important to know.

Comment: @selbie: 2-core HT (Core i5, it's a laptop), Windows 8 x64.

Comment: Does playing with the thread and processor affnity functions (e.g. SetThreadIdealProcessor, SetThreadAffinityMask, SetProcessAffinityMask) influence anything?

Comment: @selbie: Nope, those don't change anything.

Comment: Why is this a problem?  What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: @HarryJohnston: When there are 8 threads running I don't expect one of them to get 25% of the CPU time... each one should get 1/8 of the CPU time.

Comment: Are particular threads consistently getting above or below average CPU time over an extended period?

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Yeah, that's what "it stays unfair throughout the life of the application" means... have you tried running it?

Comment: I can reproduce the problem, but can't find any way to avoid it.  You might have to use a work queue or explicit synchronization (or UMT).  Incidentally, what tool gives you the window showing the CPU percentage and the deltas?

Comment: @HarryJohnston: [Process Hacker](http://meta.superuser.com/a/6056/59271)!

Answer (score 1):

Some options:

---

If (and only if) you're running Windows 7/8 64-bit (not 32-bit), or Windows Server 2008 R2 or later, you *can* bypass the system scheduler completely and take care of this yourself, although it's not a trivial undertaking!

It's [described on MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd627187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and is called **User-Mode Scheduling (UMS)**.

Partial screenshot from MSDN below - is this any use for you?

[image]

In addition, it might be an idea to disable hyper-threading in your BIOS (if appropriate) because there is some debate as to how Windows distinguishes between logical and physical cores. [See here for a discussion](http://bitsum.com/pl_when_hyperthreading_hurts.php).

There are also a few functions available like `SetThreadAffinityMask()` ([MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) and `SetThreadIdealProcessor()` which may help although personally I've found this to be a bit hit-and-miss. It's more often the case that I harm overall throughput rather than help it.

Comment: I can't really disable HT since the option isn't there (nor do I want to... nor do I understand why it changes anything). Unfortunately setting the affinity or ideal processor doesn't change anything either. UMS seems to be massively overkill and I'm not sure if it would help but +1 for at least mentioning it, it sounds like it could work.

Answer (score 1):

You will see this on a multiprocessor system whenever a thread that isn't part of your program runs. Say there is a system task that starts up to run for a couple of seconds, scanning .NET assemblies or something. It will knock one of your threads out of the scheduling for a number of time slices while threads on the other cores continue running. The thread that got knocked out will never catch up to the others.

Comment: This continues forever. I'm not counting absolute cycles, I'm counting looking at the CPU usage, which has nothing to do with the past history of the thread. Also, there is no system task etc. that's causing this -- this is the only program running, quite obviously easy to tell from task manager or tools like that.

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark guess.

But I'm going to suggest that Hyper-Threading may be skewing the results a bit.

If your laptop's bios/cmos allows disabling hyperthreading as some computers do, then it would be interesting to see the numbers with your code only running on real cores.

And even if HT is the reason why it biases on thread, then I still don't know why it would do that.

Comment: Nope I can't disable HT, and as you mentioned, it doesn't really explain what I'm getting at all.

Answer (score 0):

On my system, `SetThreadAffinityMask` seems to mitigate the issue.  There's still some imbalance, apparently due to one core having less time available than the other, but it's not as severe.

Windows seems unwilling to move these threads between cores; they rarely change core after the first second or so.  If the threads are not equally distributed between cores, the thread times reflect that.

This is the code I used to try out affinity masks:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

DWORD WINAPI ThreadStart(LPVOID arg)
{
    DWORD pn1, pn2;

    printf("Thread %u on processor %u\n", GetThreadId(GetCurrentThread()), pn1 = GetCurrentProcessorNumber());

    // The problem comes back if you enable this line
    // SetThreadAffinityMask(GetCurrentThread(), -1);

    for (;;) 
    { 
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++);
        pn2 = GetCurrentProcessorNumber();
        if (pn2 != pn1)
        {
            pn1 = pn2;
            printf("Thread %u on processor %u\n", GetThreadId(GetCurrentThread()), pn1);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    SetPriorityClass(GetCurrentProcess(), BELOW_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS);

    SYSTEM_INFO si;
    GetSystemInfo(&si);

    for (DWORD i = 0; i < si.dwNumberOfProcessors; i++)
    { 
        SetThreadAffinityMask(CreateThread(NULL, 0, &ThreadStart, NULL, 0, NULL), 1 << i);
        SetThreadAffinityMask(CreateThread(NULL, 0, &ThreadStart, NULL, 0, NULL), 1 << i);  
    }

    Sleep(INFINITE);
    return 0;
}
```

This approach also seems to mitigate the issue, though perhaps not as effectively:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

DWORD WINAPI ThreadStart(LPVOID arg)
{
    for (;;);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    SYSTEM_INFO si;
    GetSystemInfo(&si);

    for (DWORD i = si.dwNumberOfProcessors * 2; i > 0; i--)
    { 
        CreateThread(NULL, 0, &ThreadStart, NULL, 0, NULL);
    }

    for (;;)
    {
        SetPriorityClass(GetCurrentProcess(), BELOW_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS);
        Sleep(100);
        SetPriorityClass(GetCurrentProcess(), NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I suspect that we're looking at some kind of power-saving measure designed on the assumption that low-priority threads don't need fair scheduling.  (Arguably, setting a thread or process to low priority says "I don't care how much CPU I get.")